# Correctly closing a Hibernate transaction

Tags: database, hibernate, transactions, c3p0

I am investigating a connection leak in my code. We are using c3p0 to manage the connection pool and my general Hibernate use pattern is something like this:

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

try {

    EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();

    //..Work involving calls to find() and merge()

    transaction.commit();

} catch (... e) {
   //..log message, throw nicer exceptions

} finally {
   entityManager.close();
}
```

**Does this code have the potential to leak DB connections?** Do I have to explicitly rollback a transaction in the case of a failure, or is that done automatically? Does entityManager.close() ensure that DB connections are returned into the connection pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use transaction.rollback() in all your catch blocks.
The transaction will be closed without a commit then

Comment: Is there any way to do an automatic rollback? That would be a nicer solution than forcing me to catch all exceptions everywhere and explicitly rolling back.

Comment: A rollback is automaticcally perfomed on RuntimeExceptions. Take a look at this http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-tx-declarative

Comment: Good to know. Anything we can do about automatically rolling back on certain checked exceptions?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure about this